# The read and write calls of Firebase Database not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I was having this problem on my released app so I decide to create a tester app and a new Firebase project to repeat my actions and I'm getting the same problems.

I'm just trying to read and write data to RealtimeDatabase of Firebase the same way that I'm doing since learn Firebase years ago.

The `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener()` is not being called neither the `ValueEventListener.onDataChange()` or `ValueEventListener.onCancelled()`.

My code is being shown below:

**MainActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "TAG-FOR-LOG"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val ref = database.reference

        ref.child("test2").setValue("This is a test", object : DatabaseReference.CompletionListener {
            override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: DatabaseReference) {
                Log.d(TAG,"The error was $p0")
            }
        })

        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                val value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String::class.java)
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: $value")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```groove
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cqsuzanotest"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle**

```groove
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

For this moment this problem occurrence on the released version but is for an activity not very important.

[Just for complements, the **logcat** shows nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBvJX.png)

EDIT: My `google-services.json` file is updated and my rules on Firebase project dashboard are:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my router firewall.
I discovered running the program in my University network, it did run as well.
At home, I rebooted the router and the problem is gone.